# Android MediatorLiveData source subscription does not trigger

Tags: android, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

In my project I'm using a slightly modified repository pattern:

- DataSource (e.g. API, database). Provides CRUD of entities
- Repository of specific data (e.g. UserRepository, SettingsRepository) that handles reconciliation of DataSources (e.g. update database from API call). Provides basic functionality above CRUD
- ViewModel that uses repositories and creates a flow out of the calls of repositories (e.g. use UserRepository to sync user data, then SettingsRepository to sync settings for the user)
- View is databound

In my Repositories, I use exposed LiveData<*> fields to communicate state - e.g. said UserRepository would have a `currentUser` field of public type LiveData, privately MediatorLiveData, and it would be linked to a private field that holds the current user ID to be retrieved.

However, these subscriptions (using MediatorLiveData's `addSource() {}` method) for some reason do not fire.

An almost 1:1 example (replaced model name due to NDA) would be the following:

```
abstract class BaseRepository: ViewModel(), KoinComponent {

    val isLoading: LiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData<Boolean>().apply { postValue(false) }

}


class UserRepository: BaseRepository() {

    private val client: IClient by inject() // Koin injection of API client
    private val sharedPref: SharedPrefManager by inject() // custom wrapper around SharedPreferences

    private val currentUserId = MutableLiveData()

    val currentUser: LiveData<User> = MediatorLiveData()
    val users: LiveData<List<User>> = MutableLiveData()

    init {
        (currentUser as MediatorLiveData).addSource(currentUserId) { updateCurrentUser() }
        (currentUser as MediatorLiveData).addSource(users) { updateCurrentUser() }

        (currentUserId as MutableLiveData).postValue(sharedPref.getCurrentUserId())
        // sharedPref.getCurrentUserId() will return UUID? - null if 
    }

    fun updateCurrentUser() {
        // Here I have the logic deciding which user to push into `currentUser` based on the list of users, and if there's a `currentUserId` present.
    }
}
```

With this example implemented, `updateCurrentUser()` never gets called, even though the subscription to the other LiveData fields happens and is visible while debugging on the `currentUser` object.

The same subscription via `addSource` works just fine in other repositories, and they're constructed the very same way as above.

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MediatorLiveData` will not observe source `LiveData` if it does not have any observer subscribed to itself. `updateCurrentUser()` will be called as soon as you subscribe to `currentUser`.

Comment: `currentUser` has subscribers - it's being used in multiple databindings on the UI itself (`currentUser` gets passed to the ViewModel via `val currentUser: LiveData<User> = repo.currentUser`), and I have a few dependent MediatorLiveData's that pull information from said source (fields of User exposed in the VM are MediatorLiveData fields that subscribe to the VM's `currentUser` which is the repo's `currentUser`).

Comment: I have tested the code you provided and it works find as it is. Try to put log in different places to see which step is failing.

Comment: Hmm, I'm gonna try around. Any recommendations what to use instead of MediatorLiveData in repositories where I want nullable fields updated and subscribable from the outside?